# Slide-Out panel in Objective-C or NSDrawer?

Tags: objective-c, panel, slide

Maby somebody could share me with some info how to implement sliding-out panel? Because I got tired trying to customize NSDrawer as I need. I think there is some methods to implement for example NSPanel to slide-out. Am I right? If yes then how?

Comment: Yeah, I don't like NSDrawer either.