# Adding "Handle" to NSDrawer object

Tags: cocoa, slidingdrawer, drawer

[question] [Subclassing an NSDrawer's contentView to implement a completely custom drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868652/subclassing-an-nsdrawers-contentview-to-implement-a-completely-custom-drawer)

[question] [Slide-Out panel in Objective-C or NSDrawer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092419/slide-out-panel-in-objective-c-or-nsdrawer)

**Is it possible to add a 'handle' to a NSDrawer object? Ideally it would act like a button which is attached to the edge of a drawer, allowing the user to push it in order to open or close said drawer.**

I am able to create the drawer and open/close it as desired, but I dont want to place the button on my main view, or to the drawer's view (which is not terribly helpful as access is lost when the drawer is closed).

I have several iPad apps which incorporate this 'Sliding Drawer' handle but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do the same for a Mac App.

**Alternatively...Can I assign an action to a key-press (say the spacebar) instead of a button?**

Ive looked into NSEvent and KeyEvent, but that seems a bit overboard for what I am after.

Comment: A keypress is relatively easy; you just need to handle `keyDown:` in a responder that's in the responder chain (such as the window controller). I find the handle idea much more interesting.